# one table providing ids for the other tables: good or bad?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

Suppose there are three tables.

table 1
**generic_ids**
generic_id

table 2
**companies**
company_id
company_name
company_account_no
etc.

table 3
**employees**
employee_id
first_name
last_name
middle_name
position
etc.

An employee and a company have their own addresses (sometimes a number of addresses), so i put them into a separate table called **addresses**. To avoid having two tables, like **company_addresses** and **employee_addresses**, i thought my **generic_ids** table could generate ids for both **companies** table and **employees** table. Then i could join the **companies** table with the **addresses** table or **employees** table with **addresses** table and always differentiate between joining companies with addresses and employees with addresses.

There are a number of other attributes, like address.

Is it a bad idea to do it like this? Some suggestions, improvements, better ways?

Comment: I don't see any need for your first table.

Comment: @PM 77-1, thanks for the answer. the ids of the companies table and employees table are just numbers. if the numbers are the same, i won't be able to differentiate between the addresses of companies and employees when joining the companies or employees table with the addresses table, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do what you want that is probably easier/more efficient.

1) Make the id's in both tables auto increment, but with the increment in one of the tables starting so high, the first table will never reach it.

2) You can also differentiate with them having them same ID when you join the tables, by doing something like:

```
select concat("c",company_id) from companies
select concat("e",company_id) from employees
```

Then there's no conflict. In my opinion adding foreign keys just for categorization is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks a lot. :-) Could you explain why is it a bad idea to use the foreign keys for categorization? If I go with the 2nd option, I guess there could be a problem if I wanna join the employees or companies table with the other tables, or?..

Comment: Foreign keys add overhead to updating the parent and child tables, because the child table has to check to see if the id is in the parent table, and the parent table has to check to see if it has to update, delete, or set children to null. It also complicates the addition of data and defeats the purpose you're trying to achieve. To add new data, first, I have to make sure there is an appropriate ID in the ID table, and then I have to pick one from the ID table that hasn't been used. Also, it'll be easy to accidentally pick one that was used in employees, which is exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Joining the tables is no problem, since you just name one column companyID, and one column employeeID in the joined table, and then even if they have the same number, no problem; you know which is which. If you want to union the tables putting the id's into the same column, you'd use the concat from the answer to put the values into the same column (I don't know why you'd do that though) and still be clear on what's a company and what's an employee.

Comment: no prob. If you feel like I answered your question, don't forget to mark it as correct. Peace!

Comment: yeah, man, as soon as i have a sufficient reputation, i'll do that. my rep at the moment is too low...